# changing the color of connections on clicking a button in JSPLUMB

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I have designed a page a page using Jsplumb wherein users can join the blocks and verify if his/her connections are correct .

1. i want to add a button, which upon clicking  will result in change of  colors of  certain specific connection (based on Uuid of endpoints or endpoints).
2. Moreover i want to make components drag-able from one div(in which they are originally placed ) to another div